# Show that for every $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ there exists a measurable set $A\subseteq E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $m^*(A) = m(E)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Some help doing this exercise?

Obviously if $A$ is measurable so let $ E = A$ then $m^*(E) = m(A)$. 
With that we can work in the case that A is not Lebesgue-measurable? 
some help in doing this exercise? I'm completely lost...

Comment: Hint: You can get $E$ as a countable intersection of open sets.

Comment: how? $A$ must be uncountable... so how to cover it with a countable intersection of open sets?

Comment: @JoséMarín e.g. $[0,1]$ is uncountable but can be covered by a countable intersection of open intervals.

Comment: @NapD.Lover :  ok.. it is something like: $[0,1] = \cap _{n = 1}^{\infty}[0,1+\frac{1}{n})$... but how to do this in an unkown uncoutable set?

Comment: You're going to need to learn the _definition_ of $m^*(A)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Is the infimum of the volume of the covers of $A$

Comment: Of the covers of $A$ _by open sets_...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $E$ turns out to be a $G_\delta$ set.

Here is a complete answer.

For every $k\in \mathbb N$, there exists open set $E_k$ with $A\subset E_k$, such that $$m(E_k)\leq m^*(A)+\frac{1}{k}.$$
Now let $$E=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k,$$
then $E$ is a $G_\delta$ set, which is measure and contains $A$. Since 
$$m^*(A)\leq m(E)\leq m(E_k)\leq m^*(A)+\frac 1k,$$
for all $k\in\mathbb N$, it follows that $m(E)=m^*(A)$.

Comment: "Regularity"? We just need the _definition_ of outer measure...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I need more help... I know the definition but it is not clear.

Comment: @JoséMarín Sorry again for the unclearness. Please let me know whether it is clear to you now.

Comment: @JoséMarín I was about to give in and post a solution, when I saw that Feng had already done so.